# Fetching Value from Android Calculator

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, calculator

I have opened Calculator by using following code on button's Click event. So, How Can We get value from it and can set it to the EditText or TextView ?

```
case R.id.btnOpenCal:
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.android.calculator2",
                "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
        /*i.setClassName("com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator",
                   "com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator.Calculator");*/
        startActivity(i);
        break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no way to do it**. So don't get your head over this topic.

The only way to do it is

- Implement your own calculator
- There might be some open source libraries, which you could use

Comment: Ok, So this native Calculator can be used for only Calculation pupose ri8 ?

Comment: Native calculator can't be used by other apps for sure. I guess this is the only possible answer, @OP, mark this as correct answer, so the issue is resolved.